# How to query a date range in MongoDB where date is stored as an ISODate

Tags: mongodb

I have a field that looks like this:

```
{ "created_at" : ISODate("2018-02-01T05:42:03Z") }
```

However my query for date range returns a null result and I have no idea why. Here's my query in MongoDB Shell:

```
db.users.find({$and: [{"date": {$gte: new Date("2018-01-06T05:42:03Z")}},{"date": {$lt: new Date("2018-01-20T05:42:03Z")}}]})
```

Comment: `$lt: new Date("2018-01-20T05:42:03Z")}` is not matching, also the column name should be `created_at`

Comment: @Saravana I have dates in between those two dates like `{ "created_at" : ISODate("2018-01-16T05:42:03Z") }`. Is there something I missed? What do you mean by is not matching?

Comment: the date in the document is greater than `Date("2018-01-06T05:42:03Z")` but NOT less than `Date("2018-01-20T05:42:03Z")`, so it gets filtered out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just a wrong query. Revised it into something like this

```
db.users.find({ 'created_at': {$gte: new Date("2018-01-06T05:42:03Z"), $lt: new Date("2018-01-20T05:42:03Z")}})
```